# Replace last line rather than make new one

Tags: php

I use this PHP code in CLI and CGI mode

It waits a short period of time before showing the next line, I don't want to display all five at once, I want to replace Line1 with the next one and so on for all ten line.

Thank you

```
if (!defined('STDOUT'))
    define('STDOUT', null);
if (!defined('STDERR'))
    define('STDERR', null);

function buffer($stream, $message)
{
    if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli')
    {
        // CLI - output to given stream
        fputs($stream, $message);
    }
    elseif (php_sapi_name() == 'cgi-fcgi' || ob_get_level()> 0)
    {
        // Web but output buffering is on - bypass it
        $buffer = ob_get_clean();
        echo nl2br($message).str_pad('',4096);
        flush();
        ob_start();
        echo $buffer;
    }
    else
    {
        // Web without output buffering
        echo $message;
        flush();
    }
}

for ($i = 0; $i<10; $i++) {
    buffer(STDOUT, "Line" . $i . PHP_EOL);
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I want to replace example1 with the next one and so on for all five."

Comment: If I understand you correctly: You want to output multiple lines, but do not want to show them under each other, but rather replace the last line by the next one? To achieve that, this cannot be done by pure PHP; you have to output screen control commands on the command line (these are platform dependent) and have to use JavaScript or AJAX on web environments, or refresh the whole page or a frame or iframe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using flush() replace last line rather than make new one in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884902/using-flush-replace-last-line-rather-than-make-new-one-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line ending is `\r\n` meaning `go to next line and return to start of line`.
You need `\r` meaning `return to start of line` and echoing will overwrite line content.

Keep in mind this scenario:

```
echo "Hello, my name is JJ\r";
echo "Hello, it is me";
```

will provide output as

```
Hello, it is meisJJ
```

`echo` will replace only echoed amount of symbols leaving rest untouched. I suggest adding some white space to end of echo

```
function output($message, $lineLength = 80) {
    echo str_pad($message, $lineLength, ' ', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
}
```